# Scraping using python requests for this link

Tags: python

This is the link I am trying to visit
http://www.worldfree4u.me/300mb-movies/watch-online-assassination-games-hindi-dubbed-free-download/
In browser when I go to link it says page not found, after that when type name of movie "assassination games" and visit the link from search page it works. I want to do this with python requests.
Things I've tried

- in headers referer was set to search link and user-agent to ie11 ua string
- tried to make a session object with `s=requests.Session` and then in another request visiting the link above using `s.get(url,headers=headers)`

But nothing above seems to work.

Comment: What doesn't work? You need to explain what the actual problem is. The link for the resource you provided doesn't exist, so why would using a `requests.Session` help?

Comment: It doesn't exist when I go directly to "http://www.worldfree4u.me/300mb-movies/watch-online-assassination-games-hindi-dubbed-free-download/"  but when I type the movie's name in search box and then visit the link the same link exists. I don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

You can perform a search on that site using this URL:

```
http://www.worldfree4u.me/?s=<search term>
```

e.g.

```
import requests

search_term = 'assassination games'
r = requests.get('http://www.worldfree4u.me/?',params={'s': search_term})
```

will return the search results for "assassination games". You can then a HTML parser such as [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) on `r.content` to pick out the result(s) that you are interested in.

Comment: I guess I could not explain question correctly actually I want to pull the download links from <br> "http://www.worldfree4u.me/300mb-movies/watch-online-assassination-games-hindi-dubbed-free-download/"<br> but I cannot somehow get content of this page through requests it gives me 404 (even though I can access this through browser).Let me know if I'm not clear.

Comment: It gives you a 404 because the resource that you are attempting to access does not exist. Even though, the content of that page is available in the `content` attribute of the response: `r = requests.get(url); print r.content`.